# I'm having an error assigning a function to SweetAlert using Javascript and PHP

Tags: javascript, php, sweetalert

I want to show an input alert using 'sweet alert' after another success alert, and I want to sign a function to it that'll check if the written value match the given value called "codeNumber" which is basically a PHP variable.
echo '

swal({
icon: "success",
title: "We sent you an email!",
text: "An email containing a 6-digits code has been sent to you.",
});

```
swal({
  title: "Write the 6-digits code here.",
  text: "Code:",
  type: "input",
  showCancelButton: true,
  closeOnConfirm: false,
  animation: "slide-from-top",
}.then((inputValue) => {
  var rightcode = ' . $codeNumber . ';

  if (inputValue === null) {return false};
  if (inputValue === ""){
    swal.showInputError("You need to write something!");
    return false
  }

  if(inputValue === rightcode){
    swal({
      icon: "success",
      title: "Registred successfully!",
      text: "your account has been created!"
    });
  }

  if(inputValue !== rightcode){
    swal.showInputError("Wrong code!")
    return false;
  }
}));;
</script>
';
```

The error code:

```
{(intermediate value)(intermediate value)(intermediate value)(intermediate value)(intermediate value)(intermediate value)}.then is not a function
```

Answer (score 1):

You have your parentheses messed up. You're calling `.then()` on the object literal:

```js
{
  title: "Write the 6-digits code here.",
  text: "Code:",
  type: "input",
  showCancelButton: true,
  closeOnConfirm: false,
  animation: "slide-from-top",
}.then(/* ... /*)
```

What you wanted was having `.then()` called on the result of `swal()`:

```js
swal({
  title: "Write the 6-digits code here.",
  text: "Code:",
  type: "input",
  showCancelButton: true,
  closeOnConfirm: false,
  animation: "slide-from-top",
}).then((inputValue) => { // notice the closing parenthesis before .then()
```

Comment: Exactly in line 9 in exemple from original question.